# Jbpm5 store POJO in database

Tags: database, pojo, jbpm

I'm creating documentflow using jbpm5. How can I persist all changes made to an object in bussiness process, keeping the object table readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable persistence strategy to externalise the objects that you want to store in separate tables. Or you can use the auditing capabilities (WorkflowLoggers) to store the process executions in a readable way.

Comment: Could you provide some example or share a link where I can have a look?

Comment: I couldn't find any example, the only way i found is to add service task after each object change, I don't think that this is a good way. So need your help. Thanks.